# How to edit form register wordpress theme eduma

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to add a new field in the registry, but I'm not sure how to do the insert in the database with the wordpress functions, and when I search the internet I think only plugins ... wanted to do in hand.
I do not want anyone to do it for me, just tell me where I make this new field be inserted into the database

```
<?php

if ( ! class_exists( 'Thim_Login_Popup_Widget' ) ) {
    class Thim_Login_Popup_Widget extends Thim_Widget {

        public $ins = array();

        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct(
                'login-popup',
                esc_html__( 'Thim: Login Popup', 'eduma' ),
                array(
                    'panels_groups' => array( 'thim_widget_group' ),
                    'panels_icon'   => 'thim-widget-icon thim-widget-icon-login-popup'
                ),
                array(),
                array(
                    'text_register' => array(
                        'type'    => 'text',
                        'label'   => esc_html__( 'Register Label', 'eduma' ),
                        'default' => 'Register',
                    ),
                    'text_login'    => array(
                        'type'    => 'text',
                        'label'   => esc_html__( 'Login Label', 'eduma' ),
                        'default' => 'Login',
                    ),
                    'text_logout'   => array(
                        'type'    => 'text',
                        'label'   => esc_html__( 'Logout Label', 'eduma' ),
                        'default' => 'Logout',
                    ),
                    'text_profile'  => array(
                        'type'    => 'text',
                        'label'   => esc_html__( 'Profile Label', 'eduma' ),
                        'default' => 'Profile',
                    ),
                    'layout'        => array(
                        'type'    => 'select',
                        'label'   => esc_html__( 'Layout', 'eduma' ),
                        'default' => 'base',
                        'options' => array(
                            'base' => esc_html__( 'Default', 'eduma' ),
                            'icon' => esc_html__( 'Icon', 'eduma' ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    'captcha'       => array(
                        'type'        => 'checkbox',
                        'label'       => esc_html__( 'Use captcha?', 'eduma' ),
                        'description' => esc_html__( 'Use captcha in register and login form.', 'eduma' ),
                        'default'     => false
                    ),
                    'term'          => array(
                        'type'        => 'text',
                        'label'       => esc_html__( 'Terms of Service link', 'eduma' ),
                        'description' => esc_html__( 'Leave empty to disable this field.', 'eduma' ),
                        'default'     => '',
                    ),
                    'shortcode'     => array(
                        'type'        => 'text',
                        'label'       => esc_html__( 'Shortcode', 'eduma' ),
                        'description' => esc_html__( 'Enter shortcode to show in form Login.', 'eduma' ),
                        'default'     => '',
                    )

                )
            );
        }

        /**
         * Initialize the CTA widget
         */
        function get_template_name( $instance ) {
            $this->ins = $instance;
            add_action( 'wp_footer', array( $this, 'thim_display_login_popup_form' ), 5 );

            return 'base';
        }

        function get_style_name( $instance ) {
            return false;
        }

        function thim_display_login_popup_form() {
            $instance = $this->ins;
            global $wp;

            if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
                $registration_enabled = get_option( 'users_can_register' );
                ?>
                <div id="thim-popup-login">
                    <div class="popup-login-wrapper">
                        <div class="thim-login-container<?php echo ( ! empty( $instance['shortcode'] ) ) ? ' has-shortcode' : ''; ?>">
                            <?php
                            if ( ! empty( $instance['shortcode'] ) ) {
                                echo do_shortcode( $instance['shortcode'] );
                            }

                            $current_page_id = get_queried_object_id();
                            ?>

                            <div class="thim-popup-inner">
                                <div class="thim-login">
                                    <?php
                                    $login_redirect = home_url( $wp->request );
                                    $login_redirect_option = get_theme_mod( 'thim_login_redirect', false );

                                    // Set redirect url priority
                                    if ( is_singular( 'lp_course' ) && 'yes' == get_post_meta( $current_page_id, '_lp_required_enroll', true ) ) {
                                        $login_redirect = add_query_arg( array( 'enroll-course' => $current_page_id ), $login_redirect );
                                    }

                                    if ( ! empty( $login_redirect_option ) ) {
                                        $login_redirect = $login_redirect_option;
                                    }

                                    if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] ) ) {
                                        $login_redirect = $_REQUEST['redirect_to'];
                                    }
                                    ?>

                                    <h4 class="title"><?php esc_html_e( 'Login with your site account', 'eduma' ); ?></h4>
                                    <form name="loginpopopform" action="<?php echo esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php', 'login_post' ) ); ?>" method="post">

                                        <?php do_action( 'thim_before_login_form' ); ?>

                                        <p class="login-username">
                                            <input type="text" name="log" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e( 'Username or email', 'eduma' ); ?>" class="input required" value="" size="20" />
                                        </p>
                                        <p class="login-password">
                                            <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e( 'Password', 'eduma' ); ?>" class="input required" value="" size="20" />
                                        </p>

                                        <?php
                                        /**
                                         * Fires following the 'Password' field in the login form.
                                         *
                                         * @since 2.1.0
                                         */
                                        do_action( 'login_form' );
                                        ?>

                                        <?php if ( ! empty( $instance['captcha'] ) ): ?>
                                            <p class="thim-login-captcha">
                                                <?php
                                                $value_1 = rand( 1, 9 );
                                                $value_2 = rand( 1, 9 );
                                                ?>
                                                <input type="text" data-captcha1="<?php echo esc_attr( $value_1 ); ?>" data-captcha2="<?php echo esc_attr( $value_2 ); ?>" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr( $value_1 . ' &#43; ' . $value_2 . ' &#61;' ); ?>" class="captcha-result required" />
                                            </p>
                                        <?php endif; ?>

                                        <?php echo '<a class="lost-pass-link" href="' . thim_get_lost_password_url() . '" title="' . esc_attr__( 'Lost Password', 'eduma' ) . '">' . esc_html__( 'Lost your password?', 'eduma' ) . '</a>'; ?>
                                        <p class="forgetmenot login-remember">
                                            <label for="popupRememberme"><input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" value="forever" id="popupRememberme" /> <?php esc_html_e( 'Remember Me', 'eduma' ); ?>
                                            </label></p>
                                        <p class="submit login-submit">
                                            <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" class="button button-primary button-large" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Login', 'eduma' ); ?>" />
                                            <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo esc_url( $login_redirect ); ?>" />
                                            <input type="hidden" name="testcookie" value="1" />
                                        </p>

                                        <?php do_action( 'thim_after_login_form' ); ?>

                                    </form>
                                    <?php

                                    if ( $registration_enabled ) {
                                        echo '<p class="link-bottom">' . esc_html__( 'Not a member yet? ', 'eduma' ) . ' <a class="register" href="' . esc_url( thim_get_register_url() ) . '">' . esc_html__( 'Register now', 'eduma' ) . '</a></p>';
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </div>

                                <?php if ( $registration_enabled ): ?>
                                    <div class="thim-register">
                                        <?php
                                        $register_redirect = home_url( $wp->request );
                                        $register_redirect_option = get_theme_mod( 'thim_register_redirect', false );

                                        // Set redirect url priority
                                        if ( is_singular( 'lp_course' ) && 'yes' == get_post_meta( $current_page_id, '_lp_required_enroll', true ) ) {
                                            $register_redirect = add_query_arg( array( 'enroll-course' => $current_page_id ), $register_redirect );
                                        }

                                        if ( ! empty( $register_redirect_option ) ) {
                                            $register_redirect = $register_redirect_option;
                                        }

                                        if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] ) ) {
                                            $register_redirect = $_REQUEST['redirect_to'];
                                        }
                                        ?>

                                        <h4 class="title"><?php echo esc_html_x( 'Register a new account', 'Login popup form', 'eduma' ); ?></h4>

                                        <form class="<?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'thim_auto_login', true ) ) {
                                            echo 'auto_login';
                                        } ?>" name="registerformpopup" action="<?php echo esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php?action=register', 'login_post' ) ); ?>" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">

                                            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'ajax_register_nonce', 'register_security' ); ?>

                                            <p>
                                                <input placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Username', 'eduma' ); ?>" type="text" name="user_login" class="input required" />
                                            </p>

                                            <p>
                                                <input placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Email', 'eduma' ); ?>" type="email" name="user_email" class="input required" />
                                            </p>

                                            <p>
                                                <input placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Name', 'eduma' ); ?>" type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" class="input" /><!-- My Custon Field-->
                                            </p>

                                            <p>
                                                <input placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Password', 'eduma' ); ?>" type="password" name="password" class="input required" />
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <input placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Repeat Password', 'eduma' ); ?>" type="password" name="repeat_password" class="input required" />
                                            </p>

                                            <?php
                                            if ( is_multisite() && function_exists( 'gglcptch_login_display' ) ) {
                                                gglcptch_login_display();
                                            }

                                            do_action( 'register_form' );
                                            ?>

                                            <?php if ( ! empty( $instance['captcha'] ) ) : ?>
                                                <p class="thim-login-captcha">
                                                    <?php
                                                    $value_1 = rand( 1, 9 );
                                                    $value_2 = rand( 1, 9 );
                                                    ?>
                                                    <input type="text" data-captcha1="<?php echo esc_attr( $value_1 ); ?>" data-captcha2="<?php echo esc_attr( $value_2 ); ?>" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr( $value_1 . ' &#43; ' . $value_2 . ' &#61;' ); ?>" class="captcha-result required" />
                                                </p>
                                            <?php endif; ?>

                                            <?php if ( ! empty( $instance['term'] ) ): ?>
                                                <p>
                                                    <input type="checkbox" class="required" name="term" id="termFormFieldPopup">
                                                    <label for="termFormFieldPopup"><?php printf( __( 'I accept the <a href="%s" target="_blank">Terms of Service</a>', 'eduma' ), esc_url( $instance['term'] ) ); ?></label>
                                                </p>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                            <p>
                                                <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo esc_url( $register_redirect ); ?>" />
                                                <input type="hidden" name="modify_user_notification" value="1">
                                            </p>

                                            <!--                        --><?php //do_action( 'signup_hidden_fields', 'create-another-site' ); ?>

                                            <p class="submit">
                                                <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" class="button button-primary button-large" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Sign up', 'Login popup form', 'eduma' ); ?>" />
                                            </p>
                                        </form>
                                        <?php echo '<p class="link-bottom">' . esc_html_x( 'Are you a member? ', 'Login popup form', 'eduma' ) . ' <a class="login" href="' . esc_url( thim_get_login_page_url() ) . '">' . esc_html_x( 'Login now', 'Login popup form', 'eduma' ) . '</a></p>'; ?>

                                        <div class="popup-message"></div>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>

                            <span class="close-popup"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            <div class="cssload-container">
                                <div class="cssload-loading"><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
        }
    }
}

function thim_login_popup_widget() {
    register_widget( 'Thim_Login_Popup_Widget' );

}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'thim_login_popup_widget' );
```